# Why am I not getting test ads from Ad Mob on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, admob

I used 7.0.0 adMob kit. I am not receiving Test Ads. On the Google site, they have

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Requests test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed   to the console when
// an ad request is made. GADBannerView automatically returns test ads when running on a
// simulator.
request.testDevices = @[
@"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a"  // Eric's iPod Touch
];
[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
}
```

At first I had my UDID, and then I found a previous stack overflow question and found that to get the test ID number on my iPhone I had to go to 
Settings>>Privacy>>Advertising and turn off limit ad tracking. This left me with

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

```
// Requests test ads on simulators.



request.testDevices = @[

                        @"1f015e95d8a5e6e16acc1d0258ed2ebd"

                        ];// Stephen iPhone
[self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
```

This looks exactly as the example but when I run it on my device, I still get a live ad (Game of War). What am I doing wrong? I'm afraid of testing it because I do not want Google to suspend me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry google isn't going to do anything.
If you get a live ad then your doing it right.It's simply a test ad.
In fact even if you use your original Admob ID for testing nothing is going happen.
Let me tell you what I did.

1.Initialise this in your .h file

```
GADInterstitial *interstitial_;
```

2.I would suggest that you don't use the test id or what ever,just use your Admob publisher id nothing is going to happen,trust me.
So get your Admob publisher id and do this above your .m file.

```
#define MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID @"PUT_YOUR_ADMOB_PUB_ID_HERE"
```

3.To call an ad do this.

```
interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
interstitial_.adUnitID = MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
[interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
interstitial_.delegate=self;
```

To control the other aspects of the ad make use of the delegate methods,they let you control everything.
Link to those delegate methods:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/banner

Hope this helps you.Good luck.